# Painting On A Canvas And Deleting It Automatically (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here's my objective. I want to literally paint on a canvas element then automatically erase it in a quick gradual manner. The similar implementation is somewhat like this: http://mario.ign.com/3D-era/super-mario-sunshine

I want to make it simple. I just simply want to paint and then erase the recently painted stroke. Where do I start? Is there a simple approach on painting on a canvas without using any kind of plugin? I am currently using wPaint.js and it's not really what I want. Is there a way of painting on a canvas and undoing without too much complex code?

Comment: if this fiddle suits your needs : http://jsbin.com/UNahaGur/5/edit?html,js,output  i can explain how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is how to let the user draw a self-disappearing line:**

Create a polyline by saving points to an array when the user drags the mouse.

In an animation loop, clear the screen and redraw that polyline.

But each loop, leave out the earliest points (making the earliest points “disappear”).

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/LT6Ln/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
      return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
      };
    })();


    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.lineWidth=15;

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var isDown=false;
    var points=[];
    var minPoint=0;
    var PI2=Math.PI*2
    var radius=20;
    var fps = 20;
    var lastTime=0;

    animate();

    function animate() {
      setTimeout(function() {

        requestAnimFrame(animate);

        // draw a polyline using the saved points array
        // but start later in the array each animation loop
        if(minPoint<points.length){
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(points[minPoint].x,points[minPoint.y]);
            for(var i=minPoint+1;i<points.length;i++){
                var pt=points[i];
                ctx.lineTo(pt.x,pt.y);
            }
            ctx.stroke();
            minPoint++;
        }
      }, 1000 / fps);

    }

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      isDown=true;
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      isDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){
      isDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
        if(!isDown){return;}
        mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
        mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
        // accumulate points for the polyline but throttle 
        // the capture to prevent clustering of points
        if(Date.now()-lastTime>20){
            points.push({x:mouseX,y:mouseY});
            lastTime=Date.now();
        }
    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <h3>Drag to create a self-clearing line.</h3>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

**[ Update: Using complex effects instead of a simple line ]**

Sure.  You can use a spraypaint effect instead of a line.

However, this effect requires some expensive processing!

The spraypaint effect is often created by drawing multiple random 1x1 pixels around a centerpoint.

Assuming 10 droplets per “spray”, every point along your polyline requires:

- 10 X fillRect(x,y,1,1) draws on the canvas (instead of 1 X lineTo for the simple line).
- 20 X Math.random,
- 10 X Math.cos and
- 10 X Math.sin.

Here’s an example fiddle of a “spraypaint” effect: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/zJ2ZR/

Keep in mind that all this processing must take place within the small time allowed by requestAnimationFrame (often 16-50 milliseconds per frame).

Doing the expensive spraypaint on each of 20-50 accumulated points along the polyline will likely not fit inside the time of an RAF frame.

To make spraypainting fit inside the time allowed by RAF, you will need to “cache” the effect:

1. Create 1 random “spray” in a 10px by 10px offscreen canvas.
2. Create an image from that canvas using canvas.toDataURL.
3. Add that image to an array.
4. Repeat step #1 maybe a dozen times (to get a good variety of random spray images)

Then instead of context.lineTo or  spraypainting on-the-fly, just do this:

```
context.drawImage(myCachedSprays[nextSprayIndex],point.x,point.y);
```

Comment: Now, add collision detection and we have a modern version on the game snake :)

Comment: Is there a way to change the stroke? I want to make it look like it's sprayed on a wall, or a blotch instead of a digitally painted stroke.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work well when it has multiple <p> tags before and after it.

Comment: I have updated my answer with info on how to use a complex spraypaint effect instead of simple line.

Comment: Hmmmmm...multiple surrounding <p> tags would have no effect on the canvas element :-\

Comment: What happens is the mouse does not respond on the lower half of the canvas when it gets 3 paragraphs lower, and the further it goes down the heirarchy, the canvas is no longer interacting with the mouse actions.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by paragraphs.  If you move off the html canvas element then the canvas will no longer respond to mouse events.  That's how browser mouse events work.

Comment: Look here: [jsfiddle-canvas](http://jsfiddle.net/ralphcarlo/KGF6r/)

I already put it where it will not work. As it goes lower and lower the <p> tags, you can no longer draw on the canvas.

Comment: If you scroll the screen, all your mouse calculations must be adjusted for the amount of the scroll: mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY+previousScroll);

Comment: What does that mean? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I mean that if you scroll the page then the canvas coordinates will change and therefore mouse events must be "fixed" for both the original position of the canvas and for the amount the page has scrolled.  The code snip I gave you fixes your code...Cheers!

Comment: Now it works! Great! :) One last thing, I referenced on your spray paint, but it longer creates a trail unlike on a line. Also, how do you change its color?

I also would like to know if it's possible to remove the conjoining lines when clicked on another area. I was planning to make it appear like you are painting on a wall.

Comment: Btw, how can I make this work on mobile devices? As it seems, this only works perfectly on desktop browsers. :/

Answer (score 0):

Use Kinetic.js . Its is very easy to learn. By this you can add or remove any painted stroke very easly.
See the working of it from here : http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-batch-draw/